# Ajax - PHP associative array into jquery associative array via ajax/json

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following hardcoded into jquery and I want to move the code over to pull the values from a database using ajax.

I get the data back and pass it through using json_encode but I need to keep the same format.

```
 codes['851'] = new Array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');

 codes['852'] = new Array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');

 codes['522'] = new Array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','120','205','206','207','208','209');
```

Here is the php array prior to json_encode.

```
$codes = array();
codes['851'] = array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');

codes['852'] = array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');

codes['522'] = array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','120','205','206','207','208','209');
```

I am trying to keep the same format as I do not want to rewrite all the other code in the script. Is it possible to match format?

Comment: What's the current result and code?

Comment: `{"851":["11","12","20","21","23","24","30","41","43","44","45","48","50","52","53","54","55","60","70","110","120","205","206","207","208"]"852":["11","12","20","21","23","24","30","41","43","44","45","48","50","52","53","54","55","60","70","110","120","205","206","207","208"]"522":["11","12","20","21","23","24","30","41","43","44","45","48","50","52","53","54","55","60","70","110","120","205","206","207","208"]}`

Comment: why doesnt that work for you? your json has three objects (851, 852, and 522) each with the an array of values....in your success call back you can access the first element of the 851 array with data.851[0]

Comment: Perhaps I am not doing the ajax right? It's not triggering any of the code that uses the data (like the old hardcoded array did) 

`$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: ({ CodeExceptions: true }),
  url: '/Controllers/Order/OrderController.php',
  success: function (response) {
   console.log(response);
   var primaries = response;
  },
  cache: true
 });`

Comment: I don't need to access the array via data.851[0] ... need this to be in an array not a object.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right, you need format like this in your ajax responce.

```
codes['851'] = new Array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');
codes['852'] = new Array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');
codes['522'] = new Array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','120','205','206','207','208','209');
```

for PHP you need next:

```
$codes = array();
$codes['851'] = array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');
$codes['852'] = array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','110','120','205','206','207','208');
$codes['522'] = array('11','12','20','21','23','24','30','41','43','44','45','48','50','52','53','54','55','60','70','120','205','206','207','208','209');
echo 'codes='.json_encode($codes).';';
```

this is not similar visual, but equal in JS Object structure.

Comment: weird. must be my ajax code? all I am doing with the php array is json_encode.

Comment: instead of echo 'codes='.json_encode($codes).';'; can I not just create a jquery array and place the ajax response into it? the above isn't outputting anything to the variable, the response is though.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in the ajax code, I had code outside of my ajax call that wasn't being called. After I moved the methods inside the success callback of the ajax call it all worked perfectly.